Consider a cdf $F:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $F(x)\leq x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Is this a well-known property?
As the title says, I am considering a CDF $F:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $F(x)\leq x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.
This seems like a pretty basic property and I was wondering if:

There is a name for the CDFs that meet this property, or some reference(s) that includes characterizations
CDFs like $F$ meet other known properties.

One could start by noting that $x-F(x)$ is an increasing function since $F'(x)\leq 1$. Then taking x>0 and studying the hazard ratio:
$$\frac{F'(x)/x}{1/x-F(x)/x}$$
I have the intuition that it should be decreasing since $F'(x)/x\leq 1/x$ and $F(x)/x\leq 1$. But I don't want to prove it until I am sure I am going in the right direction.

I think the inequality should be either loose or for $x\in(0,1)$.

Thanks! You are right- fixed it!

A name could just be that $F$ (first-order) stochastically dominates the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, see this page.

I believe $F(x)=x^2$ is a counter example to your hypothesis. Also the deduction that $F'(x)\leq 1$ is wrong. You cannot simply take the derivative on both sides of an inequality.

@WeierstraßRamirez, what does “CDF” mean ? Could you explain it to me, please ?

@Angelo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function What do you mean?
